# plt.style.use('./deeplearning.mplstyle') is not working on vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to run the optional labs of the machine learning specialization from coursera and both main code file and deeplearning.mplstyle are in the same folder. I am getting this error.

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './deeplearning.mplstyle'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
...
171             f"styles are listed in `style.available`)") from err
172 filtered = {}
173 for k in style:  # don't trigger RcParams.**getitem**('backend')

OSError: './deeplearning.mplstyle' is not a valid package style, path of style file, URL of style file, or library style name (library styles are listed in `style.available`)
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...

What should I do to resolve this issue?